# JSON include syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

I have a rather complicated set of relationships between several models.

```
class A
  has_many :classB
  has_many :classD
end

class B
  belongs_to :classA
  has_many :classC
end

class C
  belongs_to :classB
  belongs_to :classE
end

class D
  belongs_to :classA
  belongs_to :classE
end

class E
  has_many :classD
  has_many :classC
end
```

I'm having an issue with the JSON syntax to get all the related information starting with classA. Here's what I have working so far.

```
classA.to_json(:include => {:classB => {:include => [:classC, :classE]}})
```

I can't get the syntax working to also include classD and related classE records.

**UPDATE** Actually something like this might work except that I can't mix hashes and arrays

```
classA.to_json(:include => [ :classB => { :include => { :classC => { :include => :classE } } },
                             :classD, :classE  ])
```

Note that I didn't use singular/plural in my example code above but in my real code, I am. Any insights will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: I assume `classA` is an *object* of class *A*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
classA.to_json(:include => {
  :classB => {:include => {:classC => {:include => :classE}}},
  :classD => {},
  :classE => {},
})
```

Comment: Yep, that worked, I came to the same conclusion myself, tricky little syntax bugger.

Comment: Have an up vote - adding => {} seems to be required when you have multiple relationships at a level, and at least one of which has a sub-include on it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want classE included through both class C and classD but this should work:

```
classA.to_json(:include => { :classB => { :include => { :classC => { :include => :classE } } },
                             :classD => { :include => :classE } })
```

EDIT:

```
class A
  has_many :bs
  has_many :ds
end

class B
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C
  belongs_to :b
  belongs_to :e
end

class D
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :e
end

class E
  has_many :ds
  has_many :cs
end

@class_a = A.first
@class_a.to_json(:include => { :bs => { :include => { :cs => { :include => :e } } },
                               :ds => { :include => :e } })
```

Comment: I have tried this before and it throws this nondescript error "undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Okay, then just to make sure, I assume that classA is not actually the model but an instance of classA, right? And after that, I'd check on your associations cause in your example you mix belongs_to and has_many, but the association is just named classA for example. Just make sure you use matching singular / plural syntax in your associations and to_json.

Comment: You are right, classA in the JSON line is an instance and I'm not using the proper singular / plural syntax above but in my code, I am. The :include code should all be plurals.

Comment: Except for classE which is only associated through belongs_to :classE
Sorry, I can't say for sure unless you post your actual code. I have tried my syntax with a similar setup in my own project and it works for me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "classE which is only associated through belongs_to :classE"? Based on your example, I have updated my question with something that might work but not quite.

Comment: What I meant was that since classE is a belongs_to, it should be defined as singular, not plural. I'll see if I can clarify again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you should only need one `:include =>`:

```
classA.to_json(:include => {:classB => [:classC, { :classE => :classD }] })
```