# Confusion over generating custom JSON response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Model description:

User, Widget, Purchase

```
User
has_many :purchases
has_many :widgets, :through => :purchases

Widget
has_many :purchases
has_many :users, :through => :purchases

Purchase
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :widget
```

Hope that makes sense and is correct for the below.

Right, in my controller, I have current_user.

I wish to render a nested JSON response for use eventually with jquery templates.

Like this would be ideal:

```
{
    "purchases": [
        {
            "quantity": 200,
            "price": "1.0",
            "widget": {
                "name": "Fantastic Widget",
                "size": "Large"
            }
        },
        {
            "quantity": 300,
            "price": "3.0",
            "widget": {
                "name": "Awesome Widget",
                "size": "Medium"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This:

```
render :json => current_user.to_json(:include => [:purchases, :widgets])
```

Will render some current_user details (not really relevant) and then purchases and widgets at the same level.

This works (outputs some current user details but thats not my main gripe at the moment):

```
render :json =>  current_user.to_json({:include => :purchases })
```

But obviously only outputs purchase data. I cannot get a nested include to work (should it work?) even after looking at this sample:

```
konata.to_json(:include => { :posts => {
                                     :include => { :comments => {
                                                   :only => :body } },
                                     :only => :title } })
```

From [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json) and this [existing stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653844/json-include-syntax).

So I've just got myself thoroughly confused. Help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `:include => {:purchases => :widgets}`?  I believe that's the official way to specify that the widgets should be children of the purchases.

Comment: I kept getting "undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass", I'm not sure if that was just a syntax issue or some association issue with my models? Also, because my widgets have_many purchases, isn't it around the wrong way for that to work? Or am I just plain wrong?

Comment: Ah - gotcha.  I was looking at your "this would be ideal" example, where widgets were nested inside purchases, and thought the DB relationship was the other way around.  You could try switching them, but that would have the purchases nested inside the widgets...  It'll be tricky, since you want a different nesting than your DB layout - you may just need to write some custom code to build the hash/array structure you want, and then render that.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into utilizing the as_json method in your models to get the desired output. Adding the following to your models should get you going in the right direction.

```
#users model
def as_json(options={})
   {:purchases => self.purchases}
end

#purchases model
def as_json(options={})
   {:quantity: self.quantity,
   :price: self.price,
   :widget: self.widget}
end

#widgets model
def as_json(options={})
   {:name:self.name,
   :size: self.size}
end
```

Once you've added these you'd simply user `to_json` on your user instance and it should output correctly.

Comment: I wonder if this solution is a permanent configuration which no longer allows me to specify whether I want nested objects with the different actions in the controllers. E.g. `index` shows user information only, while `show` responds with a nested data set.

Answer (score 2):

[RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) lets you craft JSON views similar to the HTML ERB views.

This blog post, "[If you’re using `to_json`, you’re doing it wrong](http://blog.gomiso.com/2011/05/16/if-youre-using-to_json-youre-doing-it-wrong/)", explains a bit of background and the shortcomings of using `to_json`.